# QWebView not displaying png images

Tags: qt5, qwebview

I have a problem with `QWebView` when it comes to displaying images(png format), my main purpose is to using it as report generator. I have read other suggestions like placing `imageformats` below application folder, set full path for images, load images from resources, validate my `html` to W3C standards, and finally test my application into another clean machine to see if the problem is just from my machine.

```
void SemesterResultsReport::printerSetup() {
    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
    printer->setFullPage(true);
    printer->setResolution(90);
    printer->setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
    printer->setPageMargins(5, 5, 5, 5, QPrinter::Millimeter);

    QPrintPreviewDialog *dlg = new QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, this);
    connect(dlg, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter *)), this, SLOT(semesterResultsReportPrint(QPrinter *)));
    dlg->exec();
}

void SemesterResultsReport::semesterResultsReportPrint(QPrinter *printer) {
    QString strStream;
    QTextStream out(&strStream);
    qDebug() << QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    QList<QByteArray> list = QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        qDebug() << list.at(i);
    }
    qDebug() << QDir(":/imgs/").entryList();

    out << "<!DOCTYPE html>"
        << "<html>\n"
        << "<head>"
        << "<title>ff</title>"
        << "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content =\"text/html;charset=utf-8\" >"
        << "<style type=\"text/css\"> "
        << "  html, body { margin: 5px; direction: rtl; }"
        << "  table { border: 1; border-collapse: collapse; float:right; page-break-after:auto !important; width: 100%; }"
        << "  th, td    { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 0; align: center; text-align: center; font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-size: 16px; page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }"
        << "  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto !important; }"

        << "  thead { display:table-header-group; }"
        << "  tfoot { display:table-footer-group; } "
        << "</style>"
        << "</head>\n"
        << "<body>\n"
        << "<table>"
        << "    <tr>"
        << "        <td rowspan=\"2\">" + QString("الشعب") + "</td>"
        << "        <td rowspan=\"2\"><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\"imgs/registered-students2.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td rowspan=\"2\"><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\"imgs/registered-students2.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td rowspan=\"2\"><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\"imgs/num-students-above-avg2.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td colspan=\"2\">" + QString("الجنس") + "</td>"
        << "        <td colspan=\"18\">" + QString("نسب النجاح") + "</td>"
        << "    </tr>"
        << "    <tr>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\"qrc:imgs/sex-male.jpg\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\"imgs/sex-male.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/math.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/physic.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/science.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/arab.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/frensh.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/english.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/3rd-language.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/physolophie.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/geographie.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/islamic.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/managment.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/contable.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/low.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/mechanic.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/electricity.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/civil.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/route.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "        <td><img class=\"vertical-center\" src=\":imgs/sport.png\" alt=\"\"></td>"
        << "    </tr>"
        << "</table>"
        << "</body>"
        << "</html>";

    // Just for debugging purposes
    QFile file("QWebViewReport.html");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        //MSG(QString("Can`t create file %1").arg(htmlFileName));
    }

    file.write(strStream.toUtf8());
    file.close();/**/

    /*
    * Prepare QTextDocument
    */
    /**/QSizeF paperSize;
    paperSize.setWidth(printer->width());
    paperSize.setHeight(printer->height());
    QTextDocument *document = new QTextDocument();
    QTextOption options;
    options.setTextDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
    document->setDefaultTextOption(options);
    document->setHtml(strStream);
    document->setPageSize(paperSize);
    //document->print(printer); 
    /**/QWebView *view = new QWebView;
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true); 
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    view->setHtml(strStream);
    view->print(printer); 
}
```

All images from `qrc` listed correctly, plugins loaded fine as I can see png jpeg gif and other formats.
My application folder:

```
│   arcicalc.edb
│   icudt53.dll
│   icuin53.dll
│   icuuc53.dll
│   Qt5Core.dll
│   Qt5Gui.dll
│   Qt5Network.dll
│   Qt5OpenGL.dll
│   Qt5PrintSupport.dll
│   Qt5QuickWidgets.dll
│   Qt5Sql.dll
│   Qt5WebChannel.dll
│   Qt5WebEngine.dll
│   Qt5WebKit.dll
│   Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll
│   Qt5WebView.dll
│   Qt5Widgets.dll
│   QWebViewReport.html
│   StudentsNotesReporter.exe
│
├───imgs
│
├───platforms
│       qminimal.dll
│       qoffscreen.dll
│       qwindows.dll
│
├───printsupport
│       windowsprintersupport.dll
│
└───sqldrivers
        qsqlite.dll
```

**Note:** 
If I use `QTextDocument`, images loaded normally.

My programming environment:

Visual studio 2013 community edition.

Qt-opensource windows-x86-msvc2013-5.4.0.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to compile my project with `qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.0.exe` version, and it is the same problem, no images shown with QWebView.
Tested on Windows XP 32-bit, and Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see imageformats directory in your application directory.

Copy `path/to/Qt/plugins/imageformats` directory into your application directory. You can remove some plugins if you don't want to use all of them.

Comment: Well add it as `imageformats`, and as `plugins/imageformats` both didn't show the images. I suppose png comes with native support with Qt if I am not wrong.